# VBO or Administration Views problems

Tags: views

It's difficult for me to judge which module is at fault, but since I enabled [Administration Views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views) to be able to filter content by name, actions stopped working. For example:

1. **Publish selected content** gives a confirmation message that the operation was successful but the content remains unpublished.
2. **Change author** lets me select a user and then displays a confirmation message but the author remains unchanged.

Recently I have also opened an issue for the [Deploy](http://drupal.org/project/deploy) module, where the action items "Add/remove to deployment plan" did not show up until I disabled Administration Views.

Is there any secret to successfully operating those modules?
(I cannot look up the issues right now as the site seems to be temporarily down).

**Module Versions**

- [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views): 7.x-3.3
- [Administration Views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views): 7.x-1.x-dev
- [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations): 7.x-3.0-rc1+11-dev
- [CTools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools): 7.x-1.0-rc2

Comment: Can anyone confirm that they are using VBO + Admin Views successfully, meaning that the actions (such as Publish selected content) perform ok when Admin Views is enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that by default the Bulk Operations actions are set to enqueue rather than be fired directly.

Comment: Also, it appears that in order to be compatible with VBO, a module has to implement `hook_action_info`, which apparently is not the case in Deploy.

Comment: Why is that a problem?  Shouldn't they still be run, just with a very small delay?